# Beamer: remove space between progress bar and title

Tags: beamer

I am trying to save some space in my Beamer presentation and design my own theme. Particularly I want to remove this space
[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the significant part of the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
   \section{Section}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
      Some content.
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what else you want to customize, here are two different approaches:

The first one replaces `\usetheme{Berlin}` with outer, inner and color themes, `Berlin` internally loads while also adding the `subsection=false` option to the `miniframes` outer theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false, footline=authorinstitutetitle]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}


\begin{document}
   \section{Section}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
      Some content.
   \end{frame}
  
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could also define your own headline template based on the original template from the miniframes outer theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{my miniframes theme}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
   \section{Section}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
      Some content.
   \end{frame}
  
\end{document}
```

Both MWEs result in the following output:

[image]